# Access VSTS Service Endpoint credentials from extension

Tags: azure-devops

I'm developing a VSTS extension.
I have configured a VSTS Service Endpoint through the portal.
I need to use the credentials of the configured endpoint in my extension code.
Does anybody know how to do this?

-Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the type of your extension, a build task?

Comment: Yes its a build extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Eddie,

I found a solution for this with your help,
I was using 0.5.8 version of the vsts-task-lib library and update it to 0.9.7 and did the following,

```
//Import the task lib 0.9.7
import tl = require('vsts-task-lib/task');

//Get the endpoint ID (a guid)
serverEndpoint = tl.getInput('serverEndpoint', true);

//Get the enpoint URL for the retrieved end point id and parse it to URL type
serverEndpointUrl: url.Url = url.parse(tl.getEndpointUrl(this.serverEndpoint, false));

//Extract authentication details from url
serverEndpointAuth = tl.getEndpointAuthorization(this.serverEndpoint, false);

//Read parameters to variable
//NOTE: You cant write this data to console, if you do write, it will write //asterisk (****) instead of real values.

username = this.serverEndpointAuth['parameters']['username'];
password = this.serverEndpointAuth['parameters']['password'];

//Pass the variables as parameters.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the service endpoint you want to use into the task.json of your build extension and then you can use it in the build task. Refer to this link for details: [Service Endpoints in Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-gb/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/service-endpoints).

And you can also look at the [VSTS Agent Task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks) in GitHub for how to use the service endpoint in a build task like [this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/FtpUpload/ftpuploadtask.ts).

Comment: Hi Eddie, Thanks for the reply. I followed the link you provided with FTP access endpoint but still I could not extract credentials from the endpoint. I'm getting error "Endpoint not present: undefined" in line serverEndpointUrl: url.Url = url.parse(tl.getEndpointUrl(this.serverEndpoint, false));

I have also added my account as an endpoint reader.

Comment: @BandR Can you share the code and task.json so that I can check where is the issue?

Comment: Is it possible to consume service endpoints in non-build task extension, say a work item form control?